# Display PHP geoJSON data into Mapbox geoJSON

Tags: php, mysql, json, geojson

I'm using Mapbox to display a map, with data coming from MySQL. I've used php to query from the database and json_encode(); to obtain my json output, but I can't seem to figure out how to call the json_encode(); to insert into Mapbox's geoJson format.

```
<?php
  require_once 'includes/database.php';
?>


<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>Display a map</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />

<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>

<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.12.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<style>
  body {margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;}


  #map {position: absolute; 
        top: 0; 
        bottom: 0; 
        width: 100%;}

  .marker {
        background-image: url('images/mapbox-icon.png');
        background-size: cover;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

    .mapboxgl-popup {
      max-width: 200px;
    }

    .maxboxgl-popup-content {
      text-align: center;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    }
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="locations">

<?php
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM stores";
  $dbquery = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

  if (!$dbquery) {
    echo 'A SQL error occured.\n';
    exit;
  }

  $geojson = array(
            'type'  => 'FeatureCollection',
            'features'  => array() 
  );


  ini_set('serialize_precision', -1);//limits float to 6 decimenal places
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($dbquery)){
          $properties = $row;
          unset($properties['longitude']);
          unset($properties['latitude']);
          $feature = array(
                    'type'  => 'Feature',
                    'geometry'  => array(
                              'type'  => 'Point',
                              'coordinates' => array((float)
                                                $row["latitude"], (float)
                                                $row["longitude"]
                                              )
                            ),
                    'properties'  => $properties
          );
          array_push($geojson['features'], $feature);

  }

  header('Content-type: application/json');
  echo json_encode($geojson, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

  $conn = NULL;

  ?>
```

jSON output:

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"features": [
    {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -118.494537,
                34.016693
            ]
        },
        "properties": {
            "stores_id": "1",
            "stores_name": "Santa Monica Beach Bicycle Rentals",
            "website": "smbikerental.com",
            "address": "1428 4th St",
            "zipcode": "90401",
            "phone": "(310) 428-5337"
        }
```

Mapbox code (this is where my json output should be inserted into):

```
</div>

<div id="map"></div>

<script>
mapboxgl.accessToken ='pk.xxx';

var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
  container: 'map',
  style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
  center: [-96, 37.8],
  zoom: 3
});

var geojson = <?php echo json_encode($geojson,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK); ?>;

// add markers to map
  geojson.features.forEach(function(marker) {

    // create a HTML element for each feature
    var el = document.createElement('div');
    el.className = 'marker';

    // make a marker for each feature and add to the map
    new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
      .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
      .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }) // add popups
      .setHTML('<h3>' + marker.properties.title + '</h3><p>' + marker.properties.description 
      + '</p>'))
      .addTo(map);
      });   
      </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you manage to solve it? If yes, could you provide the solution